# Dividing by 3 in Python decimal

Tags: python, numbers, decimal

Just curious about how decimal package deals with infinite decimal. so I tried

```py
Python 3.7.3 (default, Oct 31 2022, 14:04:00)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> from decimal import *
>>> import math
>>> Decimal(1) / 3 * 3
Decimal('0.9999999999999999999999999999')
>>> 1/3*3
1.0
>>> Decimal(1) / 3 * 3 == Decimal(1)
False
>>> math.floor(Decimal(1) / 3 * 3)
0
>>> math.floor(1 / 3 * 3)
1
```

I could guess why this working like this.
But is this expected and should I accepted this `math.floor(Decimal(1) / 3 * 3)` result?

---

ps.
I added above example to show an unexpected behaviour.
there is more BTW,

```py
>>> Decimal(1) / 3 * 3 * 6
Decimal('5.999999999999999999999999999')
>>> math.floor(Decimal(1) / 3 * 3 * 6)
5
>>> math.floor(float(Decimal(1) / 3 * 3 * 6))
6
>>> sum([Decimal(1) / 3 * 3] * 6)
Decimal('6.000000000000000000000000000')
>>> math.floor(sum([Decimal(1) / 3 * 3] * 6))
6
```

I wonder should we just be careful to floor/ceil numbers?

---

ps.

Please let me add more idea behind this question.

I was curious about handling the notorious(?) 0.1 + 0.2 issue (https://0.30000000000000004.com/) in IEE754 double precision floating point number.

Because ceiling/flooring/rounding need to convert binary to decimal, some numbers can be a infinite decimal. and I thought decimal type should have the same case which can be a infinite decimal. So, I was wonder how decimal deals with this flooring.

I was originally wondered if there is some safe way to ceil/floor/round after some arbitrary calculation, where 1 was significant.

Comment: You should probably be using [`Fraction`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) instead of `Decimal` if you want exact division of integers.

Comment: To use `Fraction`, you need `from fractions import Fraction`.  Then you can do `Fraction(1, 3)` to get an exact one-third.  And of course `Fraction(1) / 3` produces an exact one-third.

Comment: FYI, when you run `1/3*3` and see `1.0` as the output that is only because the default print format rounds the value. The actual value is still 0.9999999999. Floating point math cannot exactly represent some values. And that includes values such as 1/2 which you might naively expect to have an exact representation. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic.

Comment: @KurtisRader but 1/2 *does* have an exact representation in binary floating point, just like 1/10 does in decimal.  Actually 1/10 would be a better example, because it's not exact in binary.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe. You'd likely be comfortable if 100,000,000.999 rounded down to 100,000,000. That's pretty close, isn't it?

`Decimal` calculates with a configurable precision defaulting to 28 places. And that's not based on the 0th position like `math.floor`. `123456789` has the same significant digits as `0.123456789`. You perform a series of calculations and each one reduces precision a bit for anything truncated beyond 28 places. That's just something you have to account for in your calculation. Perhaps you end up with a confidence interval on the result.

Turning around and doing `math.floor` blows this out of the water because you've done a calculation that isn't based on the decimal precision. For instance, floor on `.99999` and floor on `99999` have different precision.

Your floor operation makes sense if you are dealing with a calculation where `1` isn't significant. if being within `1` is good enough, it doesn't matter if .9999 goes to 0. if 1 is significant, you should not be doing floor in the first place.

Another way of thinking about it is that `Decimal` is doing `floor`, but based on significant digits, not something as random as the 1's position.

Comment: I would hope that `Decimal` is doing `round`, not `floor`.

Comment: @MarkRansom - Not sure, but it doesn't make any difference. Once you reduce precision by rounding, you are off by up to .9999 of that last digit regardless of whether you drop the last digit or round at .5. I don't know the current state of affairs, but back in the day, dropping the last digit was preferred for consistency (and the practical matter that its a bit faster).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Because decimal has more precision than IEEE754 float, if my numbers fit in the float precision, I think I can safely cast into float, which leads 1 for `Decimal(1)/3*3`. But I don't know why decimal was required in the first place. Someone has suggested to use it to avoid like `math.ceil((1/10 + 2/10)*10) == 4`. but I want to find some safe way in general calculation in a modest precision like 10 digits.
BTW, could you also suggest what would you use if you want to do a flooring/ceiling where 1 was **significant**?

Comment: @tdelaney the whole point of rounding is to change your error range from (0, .9999) to (-0.5, 0.5).  The maximum amount you could be off is half.  Now of course there's a whole science to rounding, it's not as simple as that - but it's close.  I think IEEE754 demands rounding for the bottom bit.